# \[Prime]s not recognised as derivatives in some versions

Tags: pattern-matching

This is more of a warning to others than a question, so feel free to delete if not appropriate, though I do have a question as well.

I think there is a bug in some versions of Mathematica, in particular in 10.1.0 for Linux (but it's absent in 10.4.0 and 11.0.0 for Mac).

Without the bug, if one turns the expression `f''[x]` into `StandardForm`, it will format to look like `Power[f,\[Prime]\[Prime]][x]`, but the `FullForm` of it remains `Derivative[2][f][x]`.
With the bug, the `FullForm` is now the former expression, and it will no longer match patterns like `Derivative[n_][f_][x_]`.

The obvious way to avoid this bug is to not use `StandardForm`. It would be nicer however to have it work in any form, so the question is how to do that easily.

I've tried the replacement rule `Power[f_,\[Prime]\[Prime]] :> Derivative[2][f]` but this does not work. (It is cumbersome for me to test as I only have access to 10.4.0 through a cluster)

EDIT: how to reproduce this: In Mathematica 11.0.0 for Mac (for example, I assume any version, or perhaps any version without the bug), type `f''[x]//FullForm` and press command+shift+N with the cell selected to turn it into `StandardForm`. Evaluate it directly to get the proper `FullForm`, save the notebook and evaluate in Mathematica 10.4.0 for Linux to get the improper `FullForm`.

Comment: Can you give detailed steps to reproduce the problem?  Sometimes it matters how that expression is actually entered.

Comment: @Szabolcs I added it

Comment: Command-Shift-N converts to StandardForm.  Please try to be very precise.  Somehow it seems implausible to me that *this particular thing* would work differently across operating systems.  I cannot reproduce it when saving in 11.0 on OS X and opening in 10.4 on OS X.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a problem notebook, with a cell that doesn't evaluate properly in some versions.

Comment: Sorry you're right of course, edited again. I uploaded a notebook here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02708369092257130417